# Would an iframe buster affect Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense, iframe

My Adsense revenue dropped from about $10 a day to 20 cents a day on March 1st and it has been consistently at that level since then.

The only change in the code from March 1st is that we had added an "iframe buster" by setting the `X-Frame-Options` response header to `SAMEORIGIN`

Would that have had any effect on Adsense?

(We just noticed the drop today and have reverted that change to see if it has an effect)

Comment: You applied X-Frame-Options to your webpage, right? It shouldn't affect AdSense. AdSense shows ads in a cross-domain iframe, but `X-Frame-Options` on top page shouldn't affect them. Do you see ads being rendered? Any JS errors in console?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau yes ads are still visible. No JS errors in console, just a couple warnings from gtag but nothing from adsense

Comment: If you see and can click on ads then not sure. I don't think it's related to X-Frame-Options.